# TeXForm from Ryacas package as R markdown output

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, yacas

I was attempting to use the Ryacas package in generating math questions involving fractions. Below is some minimal code in R:

```
a1 = 1
a2 = 2
b1 = 1
b2 = 3

linearFactor1 = x+1
linearFactor2 = x+3

question1 = (1/linearFactor1 + 2/linearFactor2) %>% y_fn("Simplify") %>% y_fn("TeXForm")
question1
```

Output: `## [1] "\\frac{3 x + 7}{x ^{2} + 5 x + 6} "`

---

I would like to display question with an inline code block as such:

Express $`r question1`$ in partial fractions.

However, I received an output like this:

[image]

---

When using a multiline to render the math i.e. Express $$`r question1`$$ in partial fractions, I get an output where the math is rendered correctly:

[image]

---

The question is: Why is there a difference in how R Markdown renders the math, and how can I get it to render as an inline block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing space causes a problem in the in-line format `$`, but not if you render as equation with `$$`. Remove the trailing space and it should render correctly in RMarkdown. 
I am not familiar with the package but if that happens with every equation, this is how you would get rid of the trailing space.

```
# remove trailing whitespace on the right
question1 <- trimws(question1, "r")
```

Or manually

```
question1 <- "\\frac{3 x + 7}{x ^{2} + 5 x + 6}"
```

In the Rmd:

Works in line:

```
$`r question1`$
```

Works as equation

```
$$`r question1`$$
```

Comment: Tried out and it worked. Thank you for this, and for including the whitespace method too!